# flash air for android touch event DOESN`T WORK

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I was trying to make something in Adobe Flash, Air for android. I simply made a square and converted it to an Symbol (called 'hello') and I entered this code.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

hello.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, tap);

function tap(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    hello.x+=15;
}
```

but nothing happend. I even used CODE SNIPPERS, and also tested this on my phone(ALCATEL onetouch idol mini), and it also said that there are no errors.What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is your object on the display list? Is it not covered by other items? Is it an instance of an interactive object? (I assume you didn't create a "graphics" but a movieclip or a button, correct?) Does it have an INSTANCE NAME *hello*? There are many things that could be wrong, we are just guessing here.

Comment: Yes it is on display list, there are no other items, the instant name is 'hello', it is not graphics it is a movie clip.

Comment: I know as3.0, but not much. Specially about touch devices. So i used a code snipper and also browsed the internet but it just doesnt work. Touch event is new for me!

Comment: I created another file and it works WIERD.

Answer (score 0):

You set everything correctly but forget only one important thing: check if the system supports touchevent.

```
if(Multitouch.supportsTouchEvent)
```